# How to Restrict network shares access for a specific domain user in all computer except a one specific computer in a Domain Environment?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I have this requirement where: There is a particular domain User "Superuser1" in my AD Domain Controller for whom I want to set this below rules:

**Block access to network drives (network shares) and shared folders for this User** on all workstations and allow access to the same share on a particular Workstation

For example: **Block network access for Superuser1 from all PCs connected to domain except one specific PC**.

This is required because the "Superuser1" has most privilege for shared folders - So I need to restrict this user account to access network shares from only one computer

There is an option called "Deny access to this computer from the network” - but this limits access to all pc's where this GPO is applied

Is there any possible way to implement this using GPO? If not is there any other method to do this?

I tried to find answer to this but couldn’t find a match. Please help. Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Hi. Your approach should be changed. If that is a mighty user, he shouldn't be able to logon to PCs where he ain't safe.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a GPO and add Superuser1 to the "Deny log on locally" user right and then apply this GPO to all computers except the computer you want to allow them to log onto. This would prevent them from logging on locally on any computer except the computer not in the scope of this GPO.

Comment: "Deny log on locally" GPO has already been used. This works perfectly and allows user to login from only one PC ,   But I need to Block Network Shares access to this user from all other PCs except one PC , any ideas on how to do this ?